# Mailchimp: Is there a way to make the corners of coded buttons curved?

Tags: mailchimp

I used this code from another question:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <a style="background-color:#009688; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:-.5px; line-height:150%; padding-top:15px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px; text-decoration: none;" href="mailto:corporatesales@brother.com.au" target="_blank">Ask us how
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">
            <a style="background-color:#009688; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:-.5px; line-height:150%; padding-top:15px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px; text-decoration: none;" href="http://corpsolutions.brother.com.au/" target="_blank">Find out more
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And i was wondering if there is a way to make the corners of the individual button boxes more rounded, as this would match with the other buttons in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your `style` attribute:

```
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
```